# How do I exclude special price products from coupon codes?

Tags: promotions

How to `exclude from discount (shopping cart rules) products with special price`?
I want to make `discount coupon only for products with normal price`.
Is this even possible?

Comment: Maybe this solution will helpfull,
link [http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/104811/9951](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/104811/9951)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found quite simple solution:

If **ALL**  of these conditions are **FALSE** :

```
**Special Price**  greater than  **0**
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if your special prices are set by "Special price active from date" & "Special price active to date" – then you have always SpecialPrice > 0, but it's just not active...

Comment: what if special price is set but expired ??

Answer (score 10):

It is obvious things that coupon code should not apply on discount products. But there is no rule and conditions for that in magento. Here i have use a small trick and its work for me. I hope it will be use for needed people also.

Go to shopping cart price rule and click on Actions tab and follow the below image condition.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post links to your website. If you have valuable info, add it here.

Comment: what if special price is set but expired.

Comment: what if special price is set but expired ??

Answer (score 3):

Special Price is product attribute.

So enable it for promo rules creation in admin - catalog - attributes - manage attributes.

And then in the rule condition set "special price" < 1

Comment: How will this work if no special price is being added for the product?

Answer (score 2):

Ivan

I have put some easy logic with out doing any coding

Step1: `Create an attribute of type Yes/No and enable this attribute in promotion`.

step2: `Apply all special price products. assign new attribute value to yes and update in products`.

Step3: `Now got to admin > promo > shopping cart rule section and inaction tab put you logic`.

**It only excluding special price apply products.**

Let know if you have queries

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively if your `Sale Price` always contains at least one zero (e.g. 75.00).

Then you can use:

```
Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions:
    If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
        Sale Price 'does not contain' 0
```

Comment: what if special price is expired.

Answer (score 2):

This works -
Shopping Cart Price Rules
(In Actions Tab) 
SKU is not one of _____ (SKU Number). 
Below is my example for my promotion of 16% off any order over 19.95. I already have 2 products on a separate promo, so I don't want anyone to add another 16% on top of it.

**Drop Down Menu**
Apply Percent of Product Discount
Discount Amount *16
Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To 0
Discount Qty Step (Buy X) 0
Apply to Shipping Amount
Free Shipping - NO
Stop Further Rules Processing

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
Price in cart  equals or greater than  19.95
SKU  is not one of  6301, 6804