# Catalog price rule from today does not apply

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, catalog-price-rules

I am using Magento 1.9.1.0. I set up a catalog price rule which applies to all my products in my store with a discount of the 20 percent for just one day.
The catalogrule_apply_all action is supposed to be ran every day at 1am in the mornig (0 1 * * *).

I have a problem in setting the date range of the promotion. To test it, in my development environment, I set up the from_date and the end_date with the 'today' value. After applying the rule I can't see the promotion in the frontend. I need to set up the from_date back of one day to see it working.

Now I have to schedule the promotion, which will start in 2 days, for my production environment and I am not sure about which value assign to from_date field. Should I assign the day before it should be active or should i leave the real start date?

Answer (score 8):

Problem in this instance is on these lines

```
$fromTime = (int) strtotime($rule->getFromDate());
$toTime = (int) strtotime($rule->getToDate());
```

They are not using Magento time methods to take in to consideration timing zones and in the comparison it uses following line. (Few lines after the above lines)

```
$coreDate  = $this->_factory->getModel('core/date');
$timestamp = $coreDate->gmtTimestamp('Today');
```

If you update the first two lines to

```
$fromTime = (int) Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtTimestamp(strtotime($rule->getFromDate()));
$toTime = (int) Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtTimestamp(strtotime($rule->getToDate()));
```

Note that now both uses gmtTimestamp which is inline with the comparison. This should work fine. Obviously add a class override.

Comment: This solution has bug, it will set all products on sale, even if there are conditions set.

Comment: This doesn't work on Magento 1.9.3.3

Comment: please send a PULL fix request here: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts

Answer (score 2):

I also have the same issue but it was in Magento EE 1.14.2.1.  **System / Configuration / General - Locale Options** settings seems to correct.

I concluded that the problem was in the file:
Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Resource/Rule.php  Replacing the line

```
$timestamp = $coreDate->gmtTimestamp('Today');
```

with

```
$timestamp = $coreDate->timestamp();
```

So it will be

```
public function insertRuleData(Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule $rule, array $websiteIds, array $productIds = array())
{
    /** @var $write Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface */
    $write = $this->_getWriteAdapter();

    $customerGroupIds = $rule->getCustomerGroupIds();

    $fromTime = (int) strtotime($rule->getFromDate());
    $toTime = (int) strtotime($rule->getToDate());
    $toTime = $toTime ? ($toTime + self::SECONDS_IN_DAY - 1) : 0;

    /** @var Mage_Core_Model_Date $coreDate */
    $coreDate  = $this->_factory->getModel('core/date');

    // $timestamp = $coreDate->gmtTimestamp('Today');
    $timestamp = $coreDate->timestamp();

    if ($fromTime > $timestamp
        || ($toTime && $toTime < $timestamp)
    ) {
        return;
    }
```

Both should calculate the current timestamp. But based on my tests,

```
$coreDate->timestamp();
```

converts to the correct timezone offset (same as my server date and time settings), while I always end up with a 1 day before with

```
$coreDate->gmtTimestamp('Today');
```

Like what Jeroen said, it might be Magento bug.

Comment: This doesn't work on Magento 1.9.3.3

Answer (score 1):

From `Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Resource/Rule.php`

```
/**
 * Inserts rule data into catalogrule/rule_product table
 *
 * @param Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule $rule
 * @param array $websiteIds
 * @param array $productIds
 */
public function insertRuleData(Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule $rule, array $websiteIds, array $productIds = array())
{
    /** @var $write Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface */
    $write = $this->_getWriteAdapter();

    $customerGroupIds = $rule->getCustomerGroupIds();

    $fromTime = (int) strtotime($rule->getFromDate());
    $toTime = (int) strtotime($rule->getToDate());
    $toTime = $toTime ? ($toTime + self::SECONDS_IN_DAY - 1) : 0;

    /** @var Mage_Core_Model_Date $coreDate */
    $coreDate  = $this->_factory->getModel('core/date');
    $timestamp = $coreDate->gmtTimestamp('Today');
    if ($fromTime > $timestamp
        || ($toTime && $toTime < $timestamp)
    ) {
        return;
    }
```

Everything looks fine so far if you put the same for from and to date.
For the to date is date + seconds in a day - 1, so will be end of that day.

Maybe the core date is incorrect because of a conflicting timezone setting.

You could test with a test script and echo some data.

```
include('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('admin');

echo date('Ymd His', Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtTimestamp('today'));
```

Or invoke the `insertRuleData` manually and add some debug data in the resource file for testing.

```
$ruleId = 1; // Your rule id here
/** @var $rule Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule */
$rule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load($ruleId);

/** @var $resource Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Resource_Rule */
$resource = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogrule/rule');

$resource->insertRuleData($rule, array_keys(Mage::app()->getWebsites(true)));
```

Comment: I did the test as you suggested and the date returned from the method Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtTimestamp('today') is one day back the actual day. eg.: today is the 19th but my Magento prints the 18th as the today date. It seems my problem depends on it but I can not find the way to set the correct date in my Magento store.

Comment: That means your locale is of by a day. `System / Configuration / Locale options` -> set timezone correctly

Comment: which timezone should I use? The server where my store is hosted has the CDT (-5) timezone while my store is supposed to operate in CET (+1).

Comment: Use the correct one for your store, then run the testscript again

Comment: I can't understand which timezone should I use. If I set the CDT timezone and I run the testscript the today date printed is '2015-03-19 05:00:00'. I need my rule to be activated/deactive at 00:00:00 CET timezone. Leaving this setting my catalog rule will be activated/deactived at 5 am UTC time?

Comment: No, the date you are printing is the current time. So it should match your expectations(the current time) after that all goes well, because from will be today at 0 and to is today at 23.59.59. The script will run at 1.00 and will match the rules.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand which timezone should I set. Setting the timezone CET +1 while my sever is running CDT -5 does not resolve my problem, the promotions are not activated correctly. The only way that partially fixes this error is to set the store timezone to the same timezone of the server. In this way my promotions are activated/deactivated at 1am (CET+1) in the morning (instead of midnight CET timezone). However, all the references to date order, etc. are shown as 6 hours earlier the real time. I still do not understand how to correctly configure the store timezone..

Comment: Could be that Magento cron is triggered at 1 am server time, it could be that you have bumped into a Magento bug. You could try changing the cron from 1 am to 6 am and see the difference. If the problem is resolved than, we could file a Magento bug for it, using this story.

Comment: Is it not so that Magento uses unix time ? and for some countries in EU where delta time from GMT is more than 1 hour : the indexers that run @ 01:00 (rules) and 02:00 (price) ... are not triggered simply because the whole mechanism uses unix time? If someone has a fix: please share @ https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts

Answer (score 1):

**special_to_date** & **special_from_date** - not works in Rule filter.
Can use only - **special_price**

But if exist settings in product with outdate Special price,
need update Special price attributes with script like --

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
$app = Mage::app('admin');

$now = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku', 'special_price'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        'special_to_date',
        array('to' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $now))
    );


foreach ($collection as $oProduct) {
    $product = '';
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($oProduct->getId());
    $product->setData('special_to_date', '');
    $product->setData('special_from_date', '');
    $product->setData('special_price', '');
    $product->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that the function gmtTimestamp() subtract Zend_Date::TIMEZONE_SECS to return GMT timestamp from date in current timezone. When you pass a string to that function like 'Today' and your current timezone is not UTC the result will be always wrong.
To correct this, Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Resource/Rule.php line 218 change

```
$timestamp = $coreDate->gmtTimestamp('Today');
```

with

```
$timestamp = $coreDate->gmtTimestamp('Today +'.Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->get(Zend_Date::TIMEZONE_SECS).' seconds');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it was better to change the time stamp to use the local time instead of using GMT for the caluations.

```
$timestamp = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date(null, null, null, true)->get(Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem still exists in Magento 1.9.4.0. Using the solution from xelber works perfect. Just rewrite the function `insertRuleData()` in `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Resource_Rule`