# Catalog price rule doesn't apply overnight and possible incorrect time zone

Tags: catalog-price-rules, timezone, magento-1.9.2.1

Every time I update Magento I have got this probem: I have to manually applicate the catalog price rule, otherwise they don't work.

I have done the following changes:
**File** `app/Mage.php`:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');//Instead of UTC
```

**File** `Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Action/Index/Refresh.php`(local copy and none):

```
$timestamp = $coreDate->gmtTimestamp('Today');
```

with this line:

```
$timestamp = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date(null, null, null, true)->get(Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP);
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280095/magento-catalog-price-rule-disappears-at-night

Reading this question: [Catalog price rule from today does not apply](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61045/catalog-price-rule-from-today-does-not-apply)

The time zone set in`System/Configuration/Genral/Locale options` is correct, but if I run this script:

```
include('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('admin');

echo date('Ymd His', Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtTimestamp('today'));
```

it output `2015-11-07 23:00:00` instead of `2015-11-08 11:19:ss`, basically a gap of twelve hours.

**Cron Job Setting**

File: `/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/etc/congif.xml`

```
<jobs>
    <catalogrule_apply_all>
        <schedule>
            <cron_expr>0 1 * * *</cron_expr>
        </schedule>
        <run>
            <model>catalogrule/observer::dailyCatalogUpdate</model>
        </run>
    </catalogrule_apply_all>
</jobs>
```

File `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml`

```
<jobs>
    <catalog_product_index_price_reindex_all>
        <schedule>
            <cron_expr>0 2 * * *</cron_expr>
        </schedule>
        <run>
            <model>catalog/observer::reindexProductPrices</model>
        </run>
    </catalog_product_index_price_reindex_all>
</jobs>
```

Value in cronjob setting:
[image: Cron setting]

**EDIT**
Using this:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time()));
```

it outputs the time without considering the daylight save, basically one hour in advance
**EDIT 2**
Reverting the changes in `app/Mage.php`: has solved the daylight save problem