# Catalog price rule doesn't apply if the date is set to today

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules, ce-1.9.2.4

I'm trying to set scheduled catalog price rules in my store.

When applying a catalog price rule to my store it does not work when the starting date is set to the current day.

It does work when I subtract one day of the current date.

Examples (using 2016-11-21 as the current date):

- From: 2016-11-21. **Doesn't work.**
- From: 2016-11-20. **Does work.**

Is this supposed to happen? If not, what could be the issue?

I'm running Magento CE 1.9.2.4.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Problem in this instance is on these lines

```
$fromTime = (int) strtotime($rule->getFromDate());
$toTime = (int) strtotime($rule->getToDate());
```

Update the two lines to

```
$fromTime = (int) Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtTimestamp(strtotime($rule->getFromDate()));
$toTime = (int) Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtTimestamp(strtotime($rule->getToDate()));
```

You should add class to override if you can.

Please check more detail here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/82394

Answer (score 0):

Please match your date with your current store time stamp.

For example, If your current store stamp is US then please consider from date as per US not other country.

Comment: My current timestamp is 2016-11-21 12:20:10 and so is my server timestamp. So setting the catalog rule to 2016-11-21 should (in theory) work, right?

Comment: yeah it should work.. can you please give me live url? So i can check

Comment: I'm not able to do that since this is a project for a customer with valuable data.

Comment: it's ok .But there is only one possibility for locale so please check proper.

Comment: My timezone is set to Western Europe Standard Time (Europe/Amsterdam) and so is the server we're running the store on. catalog price rule dates are set using the same timezone as the store and server.

Comment: i tried with same locale and it works for me so please check your rule status.It's active or not?

Comment: Hmm that's weird, I guess it has to do with my environment then. Yes I made sure the rule is active. Which version did you use to test this?

Comment: I Used Magento version : 1.9.1.1